# Fatal error "bad config file" while installing Git for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, git

I am trying to install Git for Ubuntu 12.04, but running the git commands is giving me the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'neha'...
fatal: bad config file line 1 in /root/.gitconfig
```

Using the article [How to Install Git on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-12-04) as a reference and even after changing the gitconfig file, I still get the same error. Besides, I cannot directly open and change the gitconfig as it is in the root folder with an alert saying "*You can't view the files!*".

Can anyone help me to get Git installed?

Comment: you can access the root folder from terminal by typing sudo in front of a command. so `sudo -i nautilus` would start the file manager up with root privileges. I can not help with the main part of the question, sorry.

Comment: sudo nautilus shows only desktop inside the root folder as well. I had tried doing that. Thanks anyways

Comment: What is the EXACT git command you are running to produce that error?

Comment: Try typing in `sudo -i nautilus /` to access deeper into the system. Your Desktop shouldn't bee in the root of your system.

Comment: I was Trying git --config and git--clone.

Comment: You should not be running git as root.

Comment: The error after using sudo nautilus / is `Nautilus could not create the required folder "/root/.config/nautilus".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a mess. I would suggest the nuclear option at this point instead of just running even more stuff as root to try and forensically work out what went wrong.

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.git* ~/.git*
```

That should nuke all the rubbish you have in root. From now on, don't `sudo git` anything. Just clone into your homedir and copy files out as root if you need to. If you need to set up configuration, I would suggest only using `git config --global variable value` rather than editing the config file directly.

Comment: Yes, it seems using `sudo` for every thing was the problem. Once I changed the directory, things worked out fine. Thanks for the help.